# Notation for a sequence of normal random variables with changing mean and variance.

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, notation, time-series

What would be an accurate mathematical notation for the following:

A sequence of $T$ random variables, where each element up to $\kappa$ is a normally distributed with mean $\mu_1$ and variance $\sigma^2_1$, and each element from $\kappa$ to $T$ is a normally distributed with mean $\mu_2$ and variance $\sigma^2_2$.

I came up with something like:

$X = \{x_t:t=1,\dots,\kappa,\dots T\}$ where $x_t \sim \operatorname{N}(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$ if $t \leq \kappa$ and $x_t \sim \operatorname{N}(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2)$ if $t> \kappa$.

But I have no idea if that is correct. Does anyone know an elegant way to write this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If by elegant you mean compact, then the use of indicator function would be suitable. You can write: 
Let
$$
x_{t} \sim N(\mu_{1}1_{\{1,\dots, \kappa\}}(t) + \mu_{2}1_{\{\kappa + 1,\dots, T \}}(t),\ \sigma_{1}^{2}1_{\{ 1, \dots, \kappa \}}(t) + \sigma_{2}^{2}1_{\{\kappa + 1,\dots, T\}}(t))
$$
be a random variable for all $t = 1,\dots, T$. 

But I would say it depends on the preference of your readers. For some set of readers, doing so may not "gain" you more..., not to say the possiblity of backfiring....

Comment: If there is a concern with the knowledge, you could define what it means by an indicator function in advance. The concept itself is simple enough; and I would say it is pedagogically heuristic to "reveal" this concept.

Comment: You could write $x_t\sim N(\mu_{i_t},\,\sigma^2_{i_t}),\,i_t:=1+[t>\kappa]$ using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).